# Need to extract data from log files and print to another file, then look for uniqueness

Tags: http, parsing, logging, server

I have data from http access logs that I need to do the following:

1. Search for the pattern in all files in a specific directory
2. Write that data to another file
3. Check new file for uniqueness and remove duplicate entries

Data looks like this:

> `<IP address> - - [09/Sep/2012:17:35:39 +0000] "GET /api/v1/user/followers?user_id=577670686&access_token=666507ba-8e88-423b-83c6-9df44bee2c8b& HTTP/1.1" 200 172209 <snip>`

I'm particularly interested in the numeric part of:  user_id=577670686, which I would like to print to a new file (I haven't yet tried that part yet)...

I've tried to use sed, but I'm not really trying to manipulate the data, so it seems incredibly clumsy....looked at awk, but the data isn't really column-based and the $# designations didn't work for this data (it would be in $10, right?)  And, I couldn't see a way to get rid of the portion of data that results from using $#.  It was suggested that I use perl, so I've looked at examples in google, but it's so foreign to me.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` to extract relevant part, then `sort` an `uniq` pair to report:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*user_id=([0-9]+)&.*/\1/' access.log | sort | uniq -c
```

This will print all unique `user_id` values together with the total number of occurrences.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz...thanks for your patience.  When I output this to a file, I get what looks like the results you're saying I'll get, but the # that I was hoping would be user_id=xxxxxxx doesn't match the # I see when viewing the log as it shows number such as:  100000007556054.  What I have in my log is closer to what I originally posted:  577670686.  That's the value I was trying to get a list of uniques.  Also, after the list is a lot of what looks like the sort/unique number crunching.  Any idea how I could get rid of that?

Comment: @MikeRyan: I tried my script above with your sample line and it extracts precisely: `1 577670686` - one occurrence of `577670686` id. Can you post more sample lines so I can try my code on larger data set? Also the `sort | uniq` is there to... sort and extract unique values (counting them)

Comment: OK, I am cutting out some data at the end of each line just for privacy, but I hope that isn't what's causing my problem, but here are a few more lines:

Comment: 166.147.72.24 - - [02/Oct/2012:19:03:17 +0000] "GET /api/v1/user/following?user_id=100002134489709&access_token=8cbe4ca7-9322-4d93-a978-044275d07eb5& HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-"

66.87.7.182 - - [02/Oct/2012:19:03:12 +0000] "GET /api/v1/user/followers?user_id=635145747&access_token=4e992125-66dc-498b-aa45-39b7f76f6a3f HTTP/1.1" 200 9349 "-"

I get all of the ones that start with 10000 like the 1st entry, but I don't get the ones like the 2nd entry...

Comment: I have no idea why it won't separate the lines in the last post....new line at IP address (which I should have edited out)

Comment: @MikeRyan: The sample data you've pasted after treating with my script prints: `1 100002134489709    1 635145747` - two differnt `user_id` values occurring once. Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, but when I run this against my log file, it gets hundreds and hundreds unique "100000xxxxx" answers, but no "635145747"; yet, I know they are in there.  I could write another sed statement to purge the leading one showing hits for the unique ID, but can the original statement be modified to exclude it?  Also, I get a bunch of data below the list of #s that I don't need.  Again, could original statement be modified to exclude that data?